# The orbit map is open

Tags: topological-groups

Let a locally compact second countable Hausdorff Group $G$ acting continuously and transitively on a locally compact second countable Hausdorff topological space $X$ and let $y$ be an element in $X$ and let $H$ be the stabilizer of $y$ in $G$ and $G/H$ be   regarded as a topological space with the quotient topology and let $f:G/H \to X$ by: $f(g*H)=g*y$ . I need to show that $f$ is open. Could someone can give me help  to prove that $f$ is open?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please edit and use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) to properly format math symbols.

Comment: Welcome to MSE ^_^ what have you tried? We can help you better once we better understand what you're struggling with